# Google javascript maps getCurrentPosition

Tags: javascript, google-maps

How can i use :

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()
```

to get the coordinates of the current position .
This is the example from google site :

```
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
   zoom: 6
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
     mapOptions);

 // Try HTML5 geolocation
 if(navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
       var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,
                                   position.coords.longitude);

       var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            content: 'Location found using HTML5.'
            });
        map.setCenter(pos);
      }, function() {
           handleNoGeolocation(true);
         });
 } else {
   // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
      handleNoGeolocation(false);
 }
}
```

I tried replacing the **var pos** part to **myPos** which is a global variable , but it didn't work.
I mean i always get **myPos** undefined after the initialize() function .
what is the correct way to get the latitude and longitude navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()  in initialize function which is called when the form (window) loads ?

Comment: The geolocation service is asynchronous (so position will not be defined until the callback function runs).  [Your code as posted works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/pmmdg3cu/)

Comment: maybe you are right , how can i tell the function not continue unless getcurrentposition called ?

Comment: You are asking to take an asynchronous function, which is asynchronous for a reason, and make it synchronous...  Research/understand asynchronous functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.getCurrentPosition()` is an asynchronous function, so it takes a callback that's executed once it has those coordinates e.g.

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  console.log(position);
});
```

which will give you something like this:

```
{
  "timestamp": 1421093714138,
  "coords":
    {
      "speed": null,
      "heading": null,
      "altitudeAccuracy": null,
      "accuracy": 20,
      "altitude": null,
      "longitude": -122.4091036,
      "latitude": 37.7837543
    }
}
```

inside the callback you pass `.getCurrentPosition` you can even update variables, assuming they're declared beforehand. I'm guessing the reason your `myPos` variable is undefined is because there's a problem with the way you're hooking up to the google maps API. If you aren't using google maps, and just want to get a location, you can do something like this:

```
var myPos;

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  myPos = position;
});
```

Oh, and make sure you allow the website to access your location. In chrome, you get a bar on the top of you page saying "< website url > wants to use your computer's location [Deny] [Allow]"

Edit:

Two things wrong. You only have access to that variable inside the scope of the callback function — only once that function runs will `tmpPos` be defined. As I said above, `.getCurrentPosition` is an [asynchronous](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/async/deferred/) function. Meaning it sets up a process to grab your geolocation, but does other stuff in the meantime (in your case, it moves on and tries to update other variables to information it doesn't have yet).

Additionally, you're calling the initialize function inside of itself, so that will create an infinitely looping function that never ends. To fix this, try:

```
function initialize(){
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
  // create the map here, because we only have access to position inside of this function
  // even if we store in a global variable, it only gets updated once this callback runs

  var currentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
}

initialize();
```

Comment: i get now in myPos a Geoposition object , but if i try to access for instance latitude using myPos.coords.latitude , i get the exception : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'coords' of undefined " ,although if i open the variable there is coords section and i can see the latitude and longitude numbers. see [http://i61.tinypic.com/21l72o6.png]

Comment: There's a few things wrong. Updated my answer. Check out this resource (javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/) on callbacks, I think it will help your general understanding of asynchronous JS coding patterns